Is there any way to get a rectangular border on everypage?
So i am writing my final year master's thesis, which requires a rectangular border on every page.
The template  I am using is from IISC Thiruvananthapuram, but they do not have the option to include a border.
How can this be done?
Link to template :
This is to be done using overleaf
- This is where I am at
 - This is how it should be

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please an image of the wanted result? Can you plese show what you have so far?

Does this question gives you the wanted output?

No , because the document class should be report, all the answers for this question is with memoir and article.

Except the first answer, the others don't rely on the class. They should work with report.

I have tried everything , but they are messing up the ToC. Introduction chapter is numbered as page number 1 but in the table of contents it is showing up with pg no 2

In this case, please provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Can you show a page with running heads on top or running footer? Where should the page number go on a normal page?

Use \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put...}  to add an image on every page.  For efficiency, put the image into a savebox and only draw once.
